# Chrome Extension: create a new tab, wait for it to complete loading, execute a script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been able to load a new tab but script executes before page load.

**manifest.json :**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "cpClips",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "cpClips extension to download videos from streaming sites.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**bg.js :**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' },function(tab) {
        alert('hi');

   });

});
```

I tried using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` along with `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`, but then even the new tab won't open.

An example would be nice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The callback to `create` occurs when the tab has been created but not necessarily when the page was loaded. You need to add a listener to the [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) event as well, and look at the `changeInfo` object passed to it's callback for the `status`.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    chrome.tabs.create({url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000'}, function(tab) {
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // make sure the status is 'complete' and it's the right tab
    if (tab.url.indexOf('127.0.0.1:8000') != -1 && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
            code: "alert('hi');" 
        });
    }
});
```